# Bijectivity of set sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I've got this homework problem to prove in my introductory analysis course ... and right now, I really have no idea how to even go about that (and as such, don't really know the right questions to ask). Could you guys maybe give me few hints in the right direction?

Problem 4:
Define $\mathbb{N}_0 := \mathbb{N} \cup 0$ and $b \ge 2$. Let
$$
M_b := \{ (a_1, a_2, ...)|\forall i \in \mathbb{N}: a_i \in \mathbb{N}_0 \land a_i < b \}.
$$
A sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is called eventually constant if there is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $a_n = a_{n_0}$ for all $n \ge n_0$. Also, let
$$
X_b := \{ (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in M_b |a_n \text{ is not eventually constant in } b-1 \},
$$
ie $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in X_b$ if and only if $\forall m \exists n>m:a_n \neq b-1$.

Please show that
$$
f: M_b \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}, (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sup\{\frac{a_1}{b}+...+\frac{a_n}{b^n}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
maps the set $X_b \subset M_b$ bijectively to [0,1). Please forgive my bad translation from German.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I’m curious: what German term are you translating *terminating*? In my experience such sequences are usually called *eventually constant* in English.

Comment: Ah, that may be the case! It's called "terminierend" in German, so eventually constant pretty much sums it up. I'll change the post!

Comment: These are decimals in base $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to think about a specific case, $b=10$. Consider a number $x$ in $[0,1)$ whose ordinary decimal expansion is $0,a_1a_2a_3\ldots$. Clearly $a_k\in\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\rangle\in M_{10}$,

and

$$x=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{a_k}{10^k}=\sup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{10^k}\;.$$

$X_{10}$ corresponds to the set of decimal expansions that do not end in an infinite string of $9$’s, so it contains $\langle 5,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$ but not $\langle 4,9,9,9,\ldots\rangle$. In terms of ordinary notation, it contains the representation $0,5000\ldots$ of $\frac12$ but not the representation $0,4999\ldots$.

If you can prove the result for a specific $b$, you should be able to modify your argument fairly easily to handle the general case.